# how  to use NVidia Visual Profiler with OpenCL (on Linux)?

Tags: cuda, opencl

I'm trying to use nvvp to profile opencl kernels.
I'm running ubuntu 12.04 64b with a GTX 580 and have verified the CUDA toolkit is working fine (i can run and profile cuda code).
When  trying to debug my opencl code i get:
`Warning: No CUDA application was profiled, exiting`
Any hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to profile an OpenCL or a pyOpenCL program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068229/is-there-a-way-to-profile-an-opencl-or-a-pyopencl-program)

Comment: See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068229/is-there-a-way-to-profile-an-opencl-or-a-pyopencl-program/35016313#35016313

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvvp can only profile CUDA applications.

Comment: I feared as much, although i can find no mention of this anywhere in NVidia's documentation... Is there an alternative?

Comment: Although it is still an under development project, you can obtain a timeline view of your OpenCL application using LTPV: http://code.google.com/p/ltpv/

Comment: Actually, this is not 100% true. http://uob-hpc.github.io/2015/05/27/nvvp-import-opencl/

Comment: It's now here: http://uob-hpc.github.io/2015/05/27/nvvp-import-opencl.html

Answer (score 5):

Nvidia's visual profiler (nvvp) can be used to profile OpenCL programs, but it is more of a pain than profiling in CUDA directly.

[Simon McIntosh's](https://twitter.com/simonmcs) High Performance Computing group over at the University of Bristol came up with the original solution ([here](http://uob-hpc.github.io/2015/05/27/nvvp-import-opencl.html)), and I can verify it works.

I'll summarise the basics:

- Firstly, the environment variable COMPUTE_PROFILE must be set, this is done with `COMPUTE_PROFILE=1`
- Secondly a `COMPUTE_PROFILE_CONFIG` must be provided, a sample I use (called nvvp.cfg) contains:

  ```
  profilelogformat CSV
  streamid
  gpustarttimestamp
  gpuendtimestamp
  ```
- Next to perform the actual profiling, in this case I'll profile an OpenCL application called HuffFramework, using:

  ```
  COMPUTE_PROFILE=1 COMPUTE_PROFILE_CONFIG=nvvp.cfg ./HuffFramework
  ```
- This then generates a series of opencl_profile_*.log files, where * is the number of threads.
- These log files can't be loaded by nvvp just yet as all kernel function symbols have a leading `OPENCL_` instead of an expected `CUDA_`, thus replace these symbols with a quick script like so:

  ```
  sed 's/OPENCL_/CUDA_/g' opencl_profile_0.log > cuda_profile_0.log
  ```
- Finally cuda_profile_0.log can now be imported by nvvp, by starting nvvp and going File->Import...->Command-line Profiler, point it to cuda_profile_0.log and preso!

[image]

Comment: As sad as it makes me this answer only works below CUDA version 7.5