# Is there a way to profile an OpenCL or a pyOpenCL program?

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I am trying to optimize a pyOpenCL program. For this reason I was wondering if there is a way to profile the program and see where most of the time is needed for.

Do you have any idea how to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance
Andi

EDIT: For example nvidias nvprof for CUDA would do the trick for pyCuda, however, not for pyOpenCL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you profile a Python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: @en_Knight: Your post is about pure python. That does not help me. Could you recheck and if the posts are different please unflag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
I have figured out a way: The `Cuda Toolkit 3.1` offers a profiling for openCL (higher versions will not). From this package use the `compute visual profiler` which is the `(computeprof.exe)`. It is available for windows and linux [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-31-downloads) and can be installed alongside a new Cuda Toolkit.
It looks like this:

[image: Timings]
[image: Total time histogram]
[image: Hist 2]
[image: Hist 3]

I hope this helps someone else too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there absolutely is - you can profile the individual PyOpenCL events run on the Device, and you can also profile the overall program on the Host.

PyOpenCL events are returned by copying memory to the device, running a kernel on the device, and copying memory back from the device.

Here is an example of profiling a Device event:

```
event = cl.enqueue_copy(queue, np_array, cl_array)
event.wait()
print (event.profile.end-event.profile.start)*1e-9
```

Here is an example of profiling on the host:

```
from time import time, strftime, gmtime
start_time = time()
# ... do some stuff like the above ^
end_time = time()
print strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime(end_time - start_time))
```

I haven't seen a more comprehensive way to profile a PyOpenCL program.  Hope that helps though!

Comment: It does help, however, I was more seeking something like I posted now. Maybe this helps you too.

Comment: Cool!  Yea I haven't seen an easy way to get the visual profiler working with PyOpenCL (rather than stock OpenCL) - so if you got that working - a few more details about how you did it would be awesome!

Comment: I have a windows platform and it was nothing more than installing the Cuda Toolkit as explained in the answer below!

Comment: If you like the answer, it would be nice if you could up vote it, so I can post comments soon. Thansk ;)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [benshope's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29070063/3865876), you should enable profiling of the command queue by creating it via

```
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context, 
            properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)
```

The [PyOpenCL examples](https://github.com/pyopencl/pyopencl/tree/master/examples) contain benchmarking scripts doing some basic profiling (check `benchmark.py`, `dump-performance.py` and `transpose.py`).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Nvidia's Visual Profiler (nvvp) used to work for profiling OpenCL (even through pyopenCL) but Nvidia stopped updating it. There's a neat trick, I pulled from the pyopenCL mailinglist and got to work with nvvp using the information from [here](http://uob-hpc.github.io/2015/05/27/nvvp-import-opencl/).

The basic steps are:

1. Create a `nvvp.cfg` file, with the configuration for the visual profiler.

Example:

```
profilelogformat CSV
streamid
gpustarttimestamp
gpuendtimestamp
gridsize
threadblocksize
dynsmemperblock
stasmemperblock
regperthread
memtransfersize
```

2. Create a bash script to set the environment variables and launch the python / OpenCL / pyOpenCL process.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
export {CL_,COMPUTE_}PROFILE=1
export COMPUTE_PROFILE_CONFIG=nvvp.cfg
python OpenCL_test.py
```

This will put a log file in your work directory, which you can inspect. You can import this file into nvvp if you change every occurence of "OPENCL_" to "CUDA_". For further information follow the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

CodeXL from AMD works very well.

Comment: Care to elaborate on why you think CodeXL works well? Without more details, this answer seems more like a comment since it does not provide any value.

Comment: Sure, CodeXL is straight forward to link with the Python code that runs the OpenCl and provides very detailed statistics. It has nice interface and reasonably good documentation. I am relatively new in PyOpenCl but i could easily make use of CodeXL to optimise aspects of the code.